# Bathroom pipe persistent high-pitched tone after water is run elsewhere in the house

Tags: plumbing

The pipes in the second floor bathroom often make a high-pitched tone after water is run elsewhere in the house. The sound continues indefinitely, with a consistent tone, even when the water stops running. Briefly running water in either the sink or shower in the impacted bathroom immediately stops the tone with a brief sucking/gurgling sound.

The bathroom pipes do not make any unusual noises when they are used themselves, and generally don't start making their tone until the water stops flowing elsewhere. It seems most common when sinks are run for brief intervals, when brushing teeth, for example, or when a toilet flushes.

We pump our water from a well into a standing tank, and pump that into the house. Our pressure tank is at 38 psi. The house was built in 1981, and has mostly copper pipes, with some PEX replacements. We've had this issue for the last year or so.

It's difficult to get it to happen on-demand, though it will typically happens several times a day. Generally once the sink or shower faucet in the impacted bathroom is run briefly, the tone will not return for some time. The plumbers we've had out always insist on immediately running the faucet in the bathroom to check it, even when we tell them not to, which has made it impossible for them to diagnose the problem.

Comment: It sounds like it might more of a vent problem than a drain/supply pipe problem.  The problem goes away when you add water to the drain, maybe blocking a path to the vents.  Which should be normal.  Next plumber you get, do not tell them the problem is in the second bathroom.  Tell them it starts in the kitchen/another bathroom.

Comment: We had a loud harmonic sound coming from our master bathroom that would go away when running the shower. Turned out to be the flush valve in the toilet, weird I know but the sound completely stopped after replacing.

Comment: @matt Interesting experience. How did you determine the flush valve needed replacing?

Comment: @RobNapier To be honest, I was talking with a buddy of mine and he immediately suggested it. He was definitely right though.

Comment: @RobNapier Flush valves are cheap and extremely easy to replace, might be worth a shot.

Comment: Yeah. I'm planning to swap out another one in my basement anyway, so I need to pick one up in any case. Might as well try it out upstairs first. Thanks! Definitely easier than a vent blockage (which I'll try next if the valve doesn't help).

Comment: @RobNapier Let us know how it turns out.

Comment: Been making some progress, and may self-answer if my last changes have been successful. I strongly suspect at this point that the problem is the fill line inside the toilet. After changing the flush valve, I found the noise really localized to the toilet, and when I touch the fill line, I can make it stop, and restart when I take my finger off the fill line. I'm starting to suspect the whole fill valve is vibrating.